# How to set up a user - account - role based relationship in eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

I am working on a system where I need many users can have many accounts and they can have multiple roles per account.

How can I set that up in eloquent.

I am currently having in User model:

```
public function accounts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Account');
}

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Account')->withPivot('role');
}
```

I have a pivot table user_account where the role is defined.

My problem is that when I go

```
$user = User::with('accounts')
                ->with('roles')
                ->where('id', $user['id'])
                ->first();
```

My output is:

```js
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "John Doe",
  "created_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
  "updated_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Acme Inc",
      "type": "BUSINESS",
      "created_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
      "updated_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "account_id": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Acme Inc",
      "type": "BUSINESS",
      "created_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
      "updated_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "account_id": 1
      }
    }
  ],
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Acme Inc",
      "type": "BUSINESS",
      "created_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
      "updated_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "account_id": 1,
        "role": "SYSTEMADMINISTRATOR"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Acme Inc",
      "type": "BUSINESS",
      "created_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
      "updated_at": "2018-03-11 20:46:46",
      "pivot": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "account_id": 1,
        "role": "USER"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is for the roles to contain just the data from the pivot table with user_id, account_id and the role name. Any pointers? I would also like the accounts output to contain just one account.

Answer (score 0):

Through extensive searching on the net I actually found a solution.

You need to make an AccountUser model and add the role to the account_user table.

In the User class you set up these relations:

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\AccountUser');
}

public function accounts() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Models\Account', '\App\Models\AccountUser', 'id', 'id');
}
```

And in the AccountUser class

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}

public function account() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Account');
}
```

And in the Account class

```
public function accountUser() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\AccountUser');
}
```

Now I can do

```
$user = User::with('roles')
                ->with('accounts')
                ->where('email', $data['email'])
                ->first();
```

And I get my expected output :)

Hope this helps someone...